# Rooting note 3 - fastboot not unlocking or detecting

Tags: rooting, fastboot, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I have been reading so much trying to find the answer to this problem, but I can't find any. I am not quite sure what to do at this point.

I am running XUbuntu and I am trying to to root my SM-9005 note 3 international version. My problem is my device isn't being recognized by fastboot (I tried windows and odin never recognized my phone either).

My device is has USB debugging on. It gets recognized in adb. It gets detected in heimdall when in ODIN mode. But doesn't get detected in fastboot.

Here is some information that might be useful:

Phone running in OS

> $lsusb
>
> Bus 001 Device 018: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II], GT-I9300 Phone [Galaxy S III], GT-P7500 [Galaxy Tab 10.1]
>
> $adb devices
>
> List of devices attached
>
> ddd0b685   device
>
> $adb reboot bootloader

Now in Odin mode

> $lsusb
>
> Bus 001 Device 019: ID 04e8:685d Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II] (Download mode)
>
> $heimdall detect
>
> Device detected
>
> $sudo fastboot devices

Nothing shows up

> $sudo fastboot oem unlock
>
> < waiting for device >

It gets stuck on this and nothing happens. And there is no indication that anything is happening on the phone.

I am lost and would appreciate all the help I can get.

Thank you,

UPDATE:

I can't even get the pit file using heimdall

> $sudo heimdall print-pit
>
> Heimdall v1.4.0
>
> Copyright (c) 2010-2013, Benjamin Dobell, Glass Echidna
>
> http://www.glassechidna.com.au/
>
> This software is provided free of charge. Copying and redistribution is
>   encouraged.
>
> If you appreciate this software and you would like to support future
>   development please consider donating:
>   http://www.glassechidna.com.au/donate/
>
> Initialising connection...
>
> Detecting device...
>
> Claiming interface...
>
> Attempt failed. Detaching driver...
>
> Claiming interface again...
>
> ERROR: Claiming interface failed!

Comment: Does Heimdall work in Fastboot mode? I thought it was limited to 'Download' mode only for this. ADB would be your access to Fastboot. I could WELL be wrong on this, but if anyone knows better please let me know.

Comment: There is only two modes that I know off. Download mode and recovery mode. Heimdall and fastboot should work for download mode as far as my knowledge goes.